# Regular expression for date formats in iOS

Tags: ios, regex, nsdateformatter

In my project i need to check some format coming from server, So i want to write a regular expression to check the format.

This is the format "**03/31/2013 08:00:00**" and other format is "03/31/2003 08:00 AM/PM"

How can i check this date formats. Can any one help me.

Regards
Kiran

Comment: Hi, I got some expression like this /^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})$/ I want to use this in iOS, I didn't use Regex previously in iOS.

Comment: I think, that you must use something like `NSDate` class for this

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:\d{2}\/){2}\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2}| (?:AM|PM))?$
```

Note that it won't check for incorrect values.

Comment: Hi Can you give regex for This is the format "03/31/2013 08:00:00" this format

Comment: @kiri sorry didn't see the difference between your 2 formats. Edited so that it matches both formats you gave.

Comment: @Loamhoof can you please tell me the regular expression for the date format of `2013-06-06 10:27:15`???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `NSDate` from this string, you should use `NSDateFormetter` instead:

```
NSString * date = @"03/31/2013 08:00:00"; // source string

NSDateFormatter * date_formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[date_formatter setDateFormat: @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"]; // your date format

NSDate * result = [date_formatter dateFromString: date]; // converting
NSLog (@"%@", [result description]); // log your date result
[date_format release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer to your question about regex but, if you want to get the date from the dateString received from server you can try a trial and error method with the dateFormat of `NSDateFormatter`.

```
NSString *dateFormat1 = @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
NSString *dateFormat2 = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";

NSString *dateString = @"03/31/2013 08:00:00 AM";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat1];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
if (!date) {
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat2];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
}

NSLog(@"Date : %@",date);
```